# X-Editable working only once - Needs refresh of page

Tags: jquery, jsp, x-editable

I have a JSP page `admin_profile.jsp` where I have a simple menu system to display contents from various other JSP pages.
When a menu item is clicked, the following script is called:

```
 $("#db_viewer").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: "admin_dbupdate.jsp",
         cache: false
     }).done(function (html) {
         $("#content").html(html)
     });
  });
```

Here `#content` is a simple `<div>` where I am displaying the data from the other pages.

My `dbupdate.jsp` is using the `X-Editable` library to perform edits to a database result table using the following script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        $(".xedit").editable();
        $(document).on('click', '.editable-submit', function () {
            var x = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
            var y = $('.editable-input input').val();
            var data = "id=" + x + "&name=" + y;
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin_dbupdate.jsp",
                data: data,
                success: success()
            });
            function success() {
                alert("User Updated!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Now, the main issue (funny thing, really) here is that when I am editing the data for the first time (first time after the website loads), it edits and updates the database just fine. BUT, when I click on any other menu item and come BACK to `admin_dbupdate.jsp`, the editing feature stops working. As in, I can see the underlines on the field to be edited, but clicking on it does not have any effect.
To get back the functionality, I have to reload the page again.
Any help would be useful. Thanks!